# Bound query string result to server tag and set visible property of button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set visible property of button control from design side using server tag <%# %>. I can do it from code behind in page load method by checking query string mode value like below:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    ---

                    if (Request.QueryString["mode"] != null && Request.QueryString["mode"] == "1")
                    {
                        btndelete.Visible = false;
                        ----
                    }
                    else if (Request.QueryString["mode"] != null && Request.QueryString["mode"] == "2")
                    {
                        btndelete.Visible = true;
                        ----    
                    }
                }
```

Now instead of writing code from code behind i want to check query string mode value from server tag and returned result will be set to Visible property of button.

I have tried this way but No Luck!

```
<asp:Button ID="btndelete" CausesValidation="false" Text="<%$Resources:General,Delete%>" OnClick="btndelete_Click"
                                runat="server" CssClass="btnstyle" OnClientClick="showConfirm(this,'mdlAttendanceReportCriteriaDelete'); return false;" 
                                Visible='<%#if(Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString() == "1"){Convert.ToBoolean("false")}else{Convert.ToBoolean("true")} %>'/>



 <asp:Button ID="btndelete" CausesValidation="false" Text="<%$Resources:General,Delete%>" OnClick="btndelete_Click"
                                runat="server" CssClass="btnstyle" OnClientClick="showConfirm(this,'mdlAttendanceReportCriteriaDelete'); return false;" 
                                Visible='<%#(Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString() == "1")?Convert.ToBoolean("false"):Convert.ToBoolean("true") %>'/>


<asp:Button ID="btndelete" CausesValidation="false" Text="<%$Resources:General,Delete%>" OnClick="btndelete_Click"
                                runat="server" CssClass="btnstyle" OnClientClick="showConfirm(this,'mdlAttendanceReportCriteriaDelete'); return false;" 
                                Visible='<%#!(Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString() == "1") %>'/>
```

It run without any parser error but there is no effect at all. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this functionality ?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Call `DataBind()` method in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

then use this syntax to set the `Visible` property in aspx code:

```
Visible='<%# Request.QueryString["mode"] == "2" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
Visible='<% Request.QueryString.Get("mode") == "1"? "true": "false"%>'
```

or

```
Visible='<% if (Request.QueryString.Get("mode") == "1" ) "true" else "false" %>'
```

Comment: Sorry in both the case it throwing parser error like  "Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<% if (Request.QueryString.Get("mode") == "1" ) "true" else "false" %>' for the 'Visible' property."

Answer (score 0):

```
Visible='<%# Request.QueryString.Get("mode").Equals("1") ? Convert.ToBoolean("False") : Convert.ToBoolean("True") %>'
```

Comment: throwing parser error " Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%=Request.QueryString("mode").ToString().Equals("1") ? "False" : "True"%>' for the 'Visible' property." :(

Comment: Why convert a string to boolean rather than just using the boolean value in the first place?

Comment: Good point. I adapted it from a code where I use Convert.ToBoolean(Eval('...')). Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Plue its still throwing same error! have u checked this at ur end ?

Comment: My bad I made a typo : <%= instead of <%#. I tried the code and it works